# How come these HTTPS optimizations are not included in default config?

Tags: nginx

I'm reading about HTTPS server optimization on [nginx.org](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html). The docs recommend adding these lines
to the `http` block to minimize the number of CPU-intensive operations. They have something to do with reusing SSL session parameters to avoid SSL handshakes.

```
   http {
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ...
   }
```

I checked `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and these lines are missing. Why are they not included by default? What am I missing here? I have a 1 core VPS instance, do I need to include it to my config?